# One field value not setting for Pracelable Object

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, parcelable

I have a wrapper class which implements the `Parcelable interface`. I'm using this wrapper to pass an `ArrayList` between activities. It's working fine but one `int` field is always giving `0` when retrieving the `ArrayList` in another activity. Please find my code below. What am I doing wrong? Are there any size limitations?

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class ModelDeviceDetails implements Parcelable{
    String responseCode;
    String nickName;
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    String deviceName;
    String uniqueId;
    String batLevel;
    int usedChaseModes;
    int plannedChaseModes;
    int usedLocateNow;
    int plannedLocateNow;

    public ModelDeviceDetails() {}

    public ModelDeviceDetails(Parcel source) {
        deviceName = source.readString();
        uniqueId = source.readString();
        nickName = source.readString();
        latitude = source.readFloat();
        longitude = source.readFloat();
        batLevel = source.readString();
        usedChaseModes = source.readInt();
        plannedChaseModes = source.readInt();
        usedLocateNow = source.readInt();
        plannedLocateNow = source.readInt();
        responseCode = source.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.deviceName);
        dest.writeString(this.uniqueId);
        dest.writeString(this.nickName);
        dest.writeFloat(this.latitude);
        dest.writeFloat(this.longitude);    
        dest.writeString(this.batLevel);
        dest.writeInt(this.usedChaseModes);
        dest.writeInt(this.usedLocateNow);
        dest.writeInt(this.plannedChaseModes);
        dest.writeInt(this.plannedLocateNow);
        dest.writeString(this.responseCode);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ModelDeviceDetails> CREATOR = new Creator<ModelDeviceDetails>() {

        @Override
        public ModelDeviceDetails[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ModelDeviceDetails[size];
        }

        @Override
        public ModelDeviceDetails createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ModelDeviceDetails(source);
        }
    };
}
```

I'm passing the `ArrayList` as follows in my main activity.

```
listViewActivity.putParcelableArrayListExtra("devices",devices);
```

Retrieving the list in my `listViewActivity`,

```
deviceList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("devices");
```

I checked before sending the list and all the fields are populated correctly. In the `listViewActivity` also other fields are there correctly. But only one field always giving `0`(I guess it's giving default for `int`). Please suggest any other approach.

Comment: Reading orderliness is wrong, please read values how to write.

Comment: Sorry @mr.boyfox, I didn't get you. Can you give me little more detail please?

Comment: Your reading from parcel constructor and writeToParcel methods orderliness doesn't match. Sequence(orderliness) writing values to parcel and reading values from parcel doesn't match

Comment: Doh! Initialy(when am following the tutorial) I was thinking how the parcel will match which field to be assigned by just `readDataType()`. So this is the solution for both of my concerns. Thanks million @mr.boyfox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ModelDeviceDetails(Parcel source) {
    deviceName = source.readString();
    uniqueId = source.readString();
    nickName = source.readString();
    latitude = source.readFloat();
    longitude = source.readFloat();
    batLevel = source.readString();
    usedChaseModes = source.readInt();
    plannedChaseModes = source.readInt(); // <-------- this
    usedLocateNow = source.readInt(); // <-------- and this
    plannedLocateNow = source.readInt();
    responseCode = source.readString();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.deviceName);
    dest.writeString(this.uniqueId);
    dest.writeString(this.nickName);
    dest.writeFloat(this.latitude);
    dest.writeFloat(this.longitude);    
    dest.writeString(this.batLevel);
    dest.writeInt(this.usedChaseModes);
    dest.writeInt(this.usedLocateNow);
    dest.writeInt(this.plannedChaseModes);
    dest.writeInt(this.plannedLocateNow);
    dest.writeString(this.responseCode);
}
```

If you implement Parcable in your class right, then you can send:

```
ArrayList<ModelDeviceDetails> list = new ArrayList<ModelDeviceDetails>();
list.add(new ModelDeviceDetails(...));
list.add(new ModelDeviceDetails(...));
Intent mySendingActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MySendingActivity.class);
mySendingActivity.putParcelableArrayListExtra("details", list);
```

And get its in your activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<ModelDeviceDetails> l = b.getParcelableArrayList("details");
Log.i("MySendingActivity", "Details:" + l);
```

Comment: To be honest I didn't aware this and no where I could able to find a hint. Now I can re-factor my code to use Android preferable `Parcelable` interface. Thanks @mr.boyfox

Comment: what was exactly happenin

Answer (score 0):

No way I found to resolve this and managed it with `Serializable` instead of `Parcelable`.
**Wrapper Class**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class DeviceDetails implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public DeviceDetails(){

    }
    String responseCode;    
    String nickName;
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    String deviceName;
    String uniqueId;
    String batLevel;
    int usedChaseModes;
    int plannedChaseModes;
    int usedLocateNow;
    int plannedLocateNow;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Sending info**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MySendingActivity.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("myKey", deviceDetails);
intent.putExtras(mBundle);              
startActivity(intent);
```

above `deviceDetails` is of type `ArrayList<DeviceDetails>`.

**Receiving info**

```
ArrayList<DeviceDetails> deviceList = (ArrayList<DeviceDetails>) intent.getSerializableExtra("myKey");
```